# Пустые места в конце Grid- и flex-колонок при определенных размерах окна браузера

Tags: css, flexbox, адаптивная-верстка, css-grid

уважаемые коллеги!

Вот пациент: (http://www.lifetree.angliskiyprosto.com/). Создал grid сетку на три колонки и с автоматическим добавлением строки при переносе колонок на следующие строки:

```
.lower {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 1 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    padding: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Каждая колонка является флексбоксом:

```
.colonka {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: solid green 1px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: OpenSans;
    font-size: 21px;
}
```

Почему на определенном разрешении получается вот такая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На более мелком разрешении все выстраивается в вертикальный ряд, а как сделать так, чтобы было нормально на том размере вьюпорта, который на картинке?

Comment: grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr)) -  думаю, здесь главный именно последний. grid-template-rows: 1 1fr; --- 1 невалидное значение.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, minmax? Пробовал самые разные значения.. все равно на том или ином разрешении появляется пустОта справа.. А если совсем minmax убрать, то колонка вылезает за окно браузера по мере его ууменьшения..

Comment: Я про то, что два два одинаковых свойства grid-template-columns и последнее перезаписывает параметры первого. display: grid и должен перекидывать "невмещаемый" элемент на следующую "строчку". Если не нужно перекидывание, то достаточно просто grid-template-column: repeat(3, 1fr).

Comment: Первое свойство тоже работает, убираешь, верстка меняется соответственно.. И перенос нужен, потому что лучше, если на маленьком разрешении колонки будут вертикально, друг под другом.. А скажите, а есть способ хотя бы центрировать колонку, которая сносится вниз, пока туда не "сползли" все остальные? Если задаешь align-items, колонки расползаются по высоте, как в масонри-верстке

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qnxgjz - вот отлично видно, что работает, а что нет. Если нужно, чтобы последняя колонка центровалась - нужно использовать display: flex.

Comment: А чтобы растянулась при переносе строки на всю ширину экрана? Даже на большом разрешении? Я думал, если задать repeat (3,1fr) то любая колонка будет стремиться занять всю свободную область своей строки.. Судя, по результату, это не так..

Comment: 1fr действительно дает занять все допустимое пространство, грубо говоря repeat(3, 1fr) означает 1/3. Но в свою очередь, grid позволяет перепрыгнувший элемент быть размером с элементами "вверху". В flex подобного результата не так просто достичь, только через костыли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы *правильно* использовать размеры мобильных устройств - просто переходим на media query:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 10rem auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}
@media (max-width: 450px) {
  /* Выполняем тот же подход, но с единсвенным эелементом в строке. Можно и просто перейти на display: block, но тогда теряем правило gap */
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}
.wrapper .item {
  background: grey;
  padding: 2rem;
  height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
 </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Действительно, попробую медиазапросом..

Comment: Еще совет разобраться как работают rem/em: благодаря им можно более гибко играть с размерами шрифтов и элементами (тогда просто пропадает необходимость пытаться поместить огромные элементы в малые размеры экрана).